# What would the <img src="" /> for the following images?

Tags: image, src

What would be the `<img src="" />` for these images. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: The image source for that image is: `http://i.stack.imgur.com/jdAOy.jpg`

Comment: where you calling from out side the resource folder? if yes, ../resources/images/pd/IMG_1950.jpg or try this ../../images/pd/IMG_1950.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the following solution was: img src="resources/images/PD/IMG_1950.JPG"
Thanks for the help guys.